# javascript run function only once per button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I use vue.js to handle some button clicks and run a method. So a button like

`<button id="signup-photo-button" v-on:click="photo">{{ photoButton }}</button>`

will run this method just fine:

```
photo: function(){

   if( vm.photoButton == 'Next, Declare Your Goal')
   {
        photoUpload();                 
    } else {
        sliderSignup.unslider('next');
    }

 }
```

the trouble is a double click can run `sliderSignup.unslider('next');` twice skipping two slides, not good. I know there is the jquery function `.one()` you can use on a button click, but I use Vue. How can I run this function only once or like once every 10 secs so you cant double click real fast? I have look a lot and only see the option of a `$('#element').one('click' function(){})` via jquery which wont work for me.

Comment: Search for "debouncing" and you'll find many examples. There may also be some jQuery debouncing plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Vue Event-Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) you can use: .once

Change your code from:

```
<button id="signup-photo-button" v-on:click="photo">{{ photoButton }}</button>
```

to:

```
<button id="signup-photo-button" v-on:click.once="photo">{{ photoButton }}</button>
```

With Vue version 1 you may use a variable like in:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example-2',
  data: {
    isAlreadyClicked: true,
    photoButton: 'button demo'
  },
  methods: {
    photo: function (event) {
      if (this.isAlreadyClicked) {
        this.isAlreadyClicked = false;
        console.log('do your stuff');
      } else {
        console.log('already clicked. Do nothing');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-2">
    <button id="signup-photo-button" v-on:click="photo">{{ photoButton }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man this would be perfect, but our system is on Vue.js 1 and dont have time to migrate right now.

Answer (score 0):

Following @baao idea

```
 photo: function(){

       if( vm.photoButton == 'Next, Declare Your Goal')
       {
            photoUpload();                 
        } else {
            document.getElementById('signup-photo-button').disabled = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                 document.getElementById('signup-photo-button').disabled = false; 
    }
,10000);
            sliderSignup.unslider('next');
        }
     }
```